# writing float numbers to text in matlab

Tags: matlab, io

This is my code, i take average of array.

```
for m=1:Q
    for n=1:W
        k=k+arr(m,n);
    end      
    k=k/W
    fprintf(fid,'%d\n',k);
    k=0;
end
```

It prints values correct in command window but incorrect in text.

command window output:

```
k =   52.4665

k =    3.9971

k =   -3.5033

......
```

text output:

```
     5.246647e+01

    3.997084e+00

    -3.503343e+00

    -1.862232e+00 

...
```

Comment: Those are the same numbers. `52.4665 == 5.246647e+01` (within printing resolution). So you'd like [`fprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html) to print values in the same format as Matlab? Have you looked at `help fprintf`? or `doc fprintf`? You'll be able to get something close, but note that you can use the [`format`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html) command to change how values are displayed in the command window - you can even choose to display numbers in the form `5.246647e+01` if you like.

Comment: thanks. when i write g instead of f, it works.

Answer (score 2):

It's a formatting issue.  If you change your `fprintf` line to

```
fprintf(fid,'%1.4f\n',k);
```

you should get the same result you got in MATLAB.

Check out the formatSpec section of

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html

Comment: This will work for small values. For `abs(k) >= 1e9` Matlab prints `1.0000e+09` to the command window. However, `fprintf(1,'%1.4f\n',1e9)` returns `1000000000.0000`. This is for `format short`.